# How to handle authentication to Mongo database from Hibernate application

Tags: mongodb, hibernate, authentication, hibernate-ogm

I need to catch errors during authentication (like wrong parameters).
I find nothing about it.
I have isolted the procedure with threads. But with this bad way, the user can't understand what goes wrong

Below, my code:

```
public static boolean access(String db, String ip, String usr, String pwd){
    Map<String, String> persistenceMap = new HashMap<>();

    persistenceMap.put("hibernate.ogm.datastore.database", db);
    persistenceMap.put("hibernate.ogm.datastore.host", ip);
    persistenceMap.put("hibernate.ogm.datastore.username", usr);
    persistenceMap.put("hibernate.ogm.datastore.password", pwd);

    Thread mainThread = Thread.currentThread();
    Thread logThread = new Thread(() -> {
        Connection.EMF = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ogm-jpa-mongo", persistenceMap);
        Connection.EM = Connection.EMF.createEntityManager();
        Connection.isOpen = true;
    });
    Thread timeOut = new Thread( () -> {
        try{ Thread.sleep( 5000 ); }
        catch(InterruptedException ex){ }
        mainThread.interrupt();
    });


    logThread.start();
    timeOut.start();

    try{ logThread.join(); }
    catch(InterruptedException ex){ return false; }

    Connection.TM = com.arjuna.ats.jta.TransactionManager.transactionManager();

    return Connection.isOpen;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the credentials are wrong, an `org.hibernate.HibernateException` is thrown.

The cause of this exception contains the details returned by mongodb and it's the only way to figure out what happened.

Comment: That's true, but i can't catch it with the classic try-catch construct.

Comment: You don't have a try-catch block in your example that contains the factory creation

Comment: I did not insert it because it is useless. The exception is thrown and managed without I can do anything

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry. I thought it was useless because in case of error the waiting time is exaggerated. Would you know a way to reduce it?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by waiting time, if you mean the connection time out, you can try to set this propertiy: hibernate.ogm.mongodb.driver.connectionTimeout. You can find a list of properties in the documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/ogm/reference/en-US/html_single/#_configuring_mongodb